# CakePHP 2.2.4 cannot paginate results using HAVING clause and calculated field - Haversine formula

Tags: cakephp, pagination, having, clause, haversine

I'm trying to paginate a list of results when calculating distances using the haversine formula in CakePHP 2.2.4, but I'm getting errors around the calculated field in the having clause.

I've seriously spent weeks trying to figure this out but I can't. I've read several posts, some saying I need to override the count methods, some saying try other things but related to older versions of Cake.

Could someone PLEASE tell me **exactly** what I need to do to get this working? There must be hundreds of people out there who have tried to achieve the same thing and with success!

The code I'm using is:

```
'Business' => array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Business.is_active' => 1
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'Business.*',
            '( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(' . $location['Location']['latitude'] . ') ) * cos( radians( Business.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Business.longitude ) - radians(' . $location['Location']['longitude']  . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $location['Location']['latitude']  . ') ) * sin( radians( Business.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance'
        ),
        'group' => array(
            'Business.id HAVING distance <= 5',
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'UserReview',
            'Certification',
            'Package' => array(
                'MassageType',
                'PackageVariation' => array(
                    'order' => array(
                        'cost_in_dollars' => 'ASC'
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'distance' => 'ASC',
            'Business.name' => 'ASC',
        )
    )
```

And the error I keep getting is:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'having clause'

Please help!

Comment: why not using virtual fields here?

Comment: you would be best off using a stored procedure and stored function in mysql for this

Answer (score 0):

I also gave up after trying to find the solution for this having clause problem. It seems that its not possible in CakePHP V2. Finally i have to go with an alternate way:

```
    $expression = '( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(' . $session_lat . ') ) * cos( radians( User.lat ) ) * cos( radians( User.lng ) - radians(' . $session_lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $session_lat . ') ) * sin( radians( User.lat ) ) ) )';
$conditions[] = $expression . ' < 100';
$this->controller->Paginator->settings = array(
    'fields' => array('Item.*', $expression.' as distance'),
    'limit' => $limit,
    'order' => array('Item.id' => 'Desc'),
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'joins' => $joins,
    'paramType' => 'querystring'
);
```

So, as you can see that i've put the calculated field again in where condition. I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this case is to use Virtual Fields:

```
$this->Business->virtualFields = array(
'distance' => '( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(' . $location['Location']['latitude'] . ') ) * cos( radians( Business.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Business.longitude ) - radians(' . $location['Location']['longitude']  . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $location['Location']['latitude']  . ') ) * sin( radians( Business.latitude ) ) ) )'
);
```

After that you can use 'distance' as a field:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
  'limit' => 20,
  'order' => array('Business.distance' => 'ASC'),
  'conditions' => array('Business.distance <=' => 100)
);

$data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Business');
```

You can read more about CakePHP Virtual Fields here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html